# Installing Umbraco 6 in a virtual folder

Tags: umbraco

I am trying to install Umbraco 6.2.4 under a virtual folder (converted to application).
But when I click on Lets get started, the page keep redirecting (301) to itself.

```
http://localhost/virtualfolder
```

the virtual folder points to a sub-folder in the main website.

The documentation says that Umbraco 6 can be installed under a virtual folder.

How do I get an Umbraco 6 website running under a virtual folder?

I am running my main website under .NET4

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Resolved two weeks back. URL rewrite module in the root web.config need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved two weeks back. URL rewrite module in the root web.config need to be fixed